# EPPLUS is not getting the right cell value from cell

Tags: c#, excel, datetime, epplus

I have a three Excel cells which look like this:

[image]

"XEZ" cell formula:

[image]

When I try to get the result of the formula, which is "73", I get "-1320" instead.

I've tried three different ways EPPlus has to get a cell value but still getting the same result:

```
package.Workbook.Worksheets[hojaEvertecCr].Cells["XEZ1"].Text;
```

```
package.Workbook.Worksheets[hojaEvertecCr].Cells["XEZ1"].Value.ToString();
```

```
package.Workbook.Worksheets[hojaEvertecCr].Cells["XEZ1"].GetValue<string>();
```

I've also tried using row and column indices:

```
package.Workbook.Worksheets[hojaEvertecCr].Cells[1,16380].Value
```

EDIT: Since the value I'm trying to get is a calculation of the difference of dates, I can do it manually with C#. But I'm going to keep the question open just in case somebody knows why am I getting this result.

Comment: Perhaps you're having the same issue I've had in the past. If you use EPPlus or most other Excel libraries to put data into a spreadsheet, the data will be *in that cell*, but the cells that refer to this cell *will not be recomputed*. One solution is to manually open the file in Excel and re-save it. This causes it to recompute. I'm curious if you find another solution that does not require a human.

Comment: You may also want to add the directory this file is in to the "Trusted Locations", which can be configured through the Excel options dialog somewhere. This may be the underlying cause, as if Excel doesn't think the file is trustworthy, it'll also skip recomputation.

Comment: The max number of columns in excel 16,384.  Your formula may be exceeding the limits.  Sometimes excel workbooks get corrupted.  Try a new workbook.